# microsoft visual studio 2012 find and replace focus to find all

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When you do a search in vs 2012 via the Find and Replace (cntrl shift f) the default focus is on the Find Next. How can you set the default focus to Find All.

Because its very frustrating because it will do a very slow search on find next and I want to do a find next (just like in the prev Vs Studios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> puts default focus on "Find All".  So if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will get Find All.  If you want to select "Find Next" from this box, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while focused on this search window instead of Enter.  This tip doesn't change default focus, but it does give you keyboard access to Find Next.

If you want a search box where <kbd>Enter</kbd> does "Find Next", try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> search box.  In the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> window, you could change the search scope from "Current Document" to "Entire Solution".  Then the Enter key would Find Next through the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the **F3** function key as a workaround. Who in his right mind would think Enter key is for finding all matches instead of cycling through each find?